# How to include stasm library in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, stasm

Using Cmake, I made Stasm library... I referenced this https://github.com/juan-cardelino/stasm
but after making library, I don't how to include this library in vs10. there is no include folder. please teach me how to include library...

[image: this is the library made by Cmake.]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Visual studio installation directory and open VC if using Cpp or VC# if using C#.
then inside you will found a include folder
paste the library file there .
its done
if you open the include folder you will also see many library header.
Hope this help you.
then in your program Type #include 
Please Vote If this Worked